# Java : Full GC (Permanent Generation Full) happening randomly

Tags: java, garbage-collection, permgen

I have configured for my java application the following parameters -Xmx = 46g, -Xms = 46g, NewSize = 2g.

We did not configure size for permgen but in JCONSOLE it shows the max perm gen size as 83mb.

While running stability tests we could see that randomly I get the following in GC logs.

> [Full GC (Permanent Generation Full)489.822: [CMS:
>   11384171K->4403070K(46137344K), 10.9407280 secs]
>   11572765K->4403070K(48024832K), [CMS Perm : 37142K->37062K(37376K)],
>   10.9413340 secs] [Times: user=10.80 sys=0.13, real=10.94 secs]

I could not find the reason for this GC call since there is free space for permanent generation (since 83 mb is shown as max value and commited perm gen memory was shown as appx 37MB).

Could you please share your thoughts on the same ?

Thanks
JK

Answer (score 2):

Even though your *max* PermGen may be 83 MB, the JVM has only allocated 36,5 MB at the point of the log above. It seems fair to assume that the JVM does a full GC and tries to continue with whatever is released, before it requests more memory from the OS to expand its PermGen space (up to the max of 83 MB).

You can try setting the initial PermGen size with `-XX:PermSize`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.  If the used permgen size reaches the commited perm gen size then JVM does a full gc ?. I thought JVM will increase the commited perm gen size automatically without doing full gc (since already enough space upto 83 mb is available).

Comment: @JK_007 The JVM will indeed (unfortunately) need a full GC to grow the perm gen.

Comment: Thank You.. As suggested then I will use the option -XX:PermSize and -XX:MaxPermSize and set the same as 83MB.